# Force to update output when shiny app is loading

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, shinydashboard

I am using leaflet and shinydashboard to create shiny app which have multiple menus which have a problem of `leaftletProxy`.

Here I created minimum example to show my question (https://gist.github.com/byzheng/074c3c1ff75ea9f951f5).

In the app, there are two sidebar menus 1) the first menu has a link `click me`; 2) the second menu has a leaflet map. After clicking `click me` in the first page, the second page is enabled and then `setView` of leaflet map to a random place.

The problem is the js console has an error message `Couldn't find map with id map` when the `click me` is clicked in the first time and `leafletProxy` is called.

I think this problem is related with leaflet map isn't initialized when shiny app is loading. After clicking more than one time, everything is working as expected.

So my question is how to force shiny to draw leaflet map when shiny app is loading.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the code creating the leaflet map is suspended while the `output$map` is hidden.

One way to fix this could be to use:

```
outputOptions(output,"map",suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
```

Unfortunately this seems to be buggy right now but could be fixed soon, it currently throws a js error ([see here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1102)).

Since `output$summary` seems to be run after the `renderLeaflet`, you could use `setView` in that block as a temporary solution.

```
output$summary <- renderPrint({
      leafletProxy('map') %>% setView(runif(1) * 30 +2, runif(1) * 30 + 2, 7)
      print(input$mydata)
      print(leafletProxy('map')$id)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put a `need` in your reactive. For example:

```
need(input$button, "Click the button")
```

Documentation here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/validate.html

Or you could just return when the proxy is `NULL`:

```
if (is.null(proxy)) {
    return(NULL)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Could you give a fill example?